# An odd multiple of 3 which is not a divisor of any 'power of 2 minus 1'

Tags: number-theory

Is there a way to generate an odd integer $n$ such that $\forall{k\in\mathbb{N}}:3n\nmid2^k-1$?

I know that $\forall{k\in\mathbb{N}}:3\mid2^{2k}-1$.

This is obvious because $2^{2k}-1=(2^k+1)(2^k-1)$.

And since $3$ doesn't divide $2^k$, it divides either $2^k+1$ or $2^k-1$.

But that doesn't seem to rule out a lot of candidates relatively to how fast it grows.

So it feels like there's a good chance for finding such an odd integer.

Is there a way to generate one, or has it been proven that no such value exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All odd numbers are divisible into one less than some power of $2$. By Euler's Theorem, if $n$ is prime to $2$, thus if $n$ is odd, then $2^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\bmod n$ where $\phi(n)$ is the Euler totient of $n$. For instance, $\phi(9)=6$ so we are sure that $9|(2^6-1)$.

Answer (score 4):

Given an odd integer $m=3n$, consider the remainders $2^k\bmod m$ for $k=1,2,3,\ldots$. As there are inifinitely many $k$ and only finitely many remainders, we find $k_1>k_2\ge1$ with $2^{k_1}\equiv 2^{k_2}\pmod m$. Let $k=k_1-k_2\ge1$. As $2$ is coprime to $m$, we can cancel $k_2$ factors of $2$ to arrive at $2^{k_1-k_2}\equiv 1\pmod m$, or
$$ 3n\mid 2^{k}-1.$$